# How is mankind important to nature?

Tags: human-biology, biochemistry, zoology, life, environment

Like mosquito eggs are important for fish, what’s our role in balancing the life on earth or its ecosystem.
Please suggest if this question doesn't fit in this community.
I am a mechanical engineer with interest in knowing biology and biochemistry.

Comment: Hi and welcome to BIO.SE. Although humans clearly play a major ecological role in the world, the wording/focus of your question (specifically within the context of your use of the word "role") causes your question (and therefore any answers) to be opinion-driven. You can try to to read up on top-down control of ecosystems, given that we are clearly top predators.

Answer (score 4):

The classical division of humans and animals has always been self-centered and artificial. Humans are animals, competing with other organisms under exactly the same rules. Evolution involves trade-offs, strategies, and adaptation. Humans have been set on a path to use their brains to compete, rather than claws. But the concepts are the same. It happens that this is a very effective strategy, such that humans now dominate virtually every ecosystem on Earth, to the point that some are now calling the age we live in as the "Anthropocene". Humans are the apex predator. We now have no natural enemies, however as vectors of disease, mosquitos control our populations more than any other animal.

Comment: very useful @KarlKjer
Can we say, human is producer of enough carbon dioxide-- useful for photosynthesis? Though I know, we have been brutal to nature in all the ways.

Comment: The carbon dioxide we produce has a benefit to Northern climates, but  is balanced by the detrimental effects of warming in the tropics. Given that plants are also evolved to live in the climates where they exist, and are often tightly linked to their pollinators, the potential decoupling of this relationship with increasing temperatures is not beneficial to plants. Some crops in some places will produce more (as the planet and most life on it suffers)